# Will installing windows format the disk?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, formatting

I have a problem with my hard disk so I removed it, stripped off an external hard disk and inserted it into my laptop. Now i want to install windows 7 on this disk but the installation is not showing me format and disk partition option. I want to know if my hard disk will be formatted if I go on with the installation?

Comment: When you choose custom installation at the time of installing instructions of Windows then tgere is an option **Drive options** which will show you advance option for a selected partition.

Comment: @avirk i know but all the options are greyed out

Comment: The options shouldn't be greyed-out. See [How to Do a Clean Installation with Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1649-clean-install-windows-7-a.html).

Comment: If all else fails you can always use GParted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a windows XP operating system disc with you, then try to do partition by using it and then insert windows 7 disc and go on with the installation.

Comment: Can you explain why the XP disc would work but the Win7 one wouldn't?

Comment: because i have noticed that there is a possibility of changing basic disk to dynamic when windows 7 disk is used. this happens when we create more than 3 primary partitions. so to avoid such issues windows xp disk is better.