# I cannot format my PC

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, ssd

I have a Toshiba Satellite(1) l505 with 6gb RAM and a 6.00 GB hard disk.

Initially I had motherboard problems with another satellite (#2). Since I have HDD problems with the first one (#1) I decided to use the hard disk of #2 in #1.

I formatted the HDD and erased the partitions it had into 1 partition (or no partition).

The problem is that when I try to format with the OS CD, in the screen where I have to decide in which partition I want to install the OS, the only one option I have says "unallocated partition", and I receive the message "Windows cannot install the OS in this partition, run files do not exist or maybe corrupted".

When I erased the disk with Parted Magic, did I erased any files needed for running the installiation disk? Is it possible to fix or reinstate the disk to install the OS?

I checked the disk physical health with Parted Magic, and it is OK. One more thing when I erased the disc to 0, I used the safety option offered by the Parted Magic.

Comment: You've used both SO and OS. Is SO a typo?

Comment: Jesus I have edited your question to make it more readable, but it's still not clear. In what machine (#1, #2) did you do what? Make the story strictly chronological and don't add information at the end that points back to the beginning (leaving us to re-assemble your chain of actions).

Answer (score 1):

Computer 1 has hard drive issues.

Computer 2 had motherboard issues.

You took the hard drive from computer 2, and tried to use it in computer 1.  You used third party software to erase the hard drive and create, as you say...

> 1 partition (or no partition)

... but you aren't actually sure whether you created a partition or not.

Insert your Windows 7 installation CD.  Follow the prompts to allow the Windows 7 installer to wipe the hard disk and create any partitions necessary.  That means when you hit the screen in the installation process that wants to know what partition you want to install to, choose the Custom Options link at the bottom right.  Then, select all the existing partitions, and Delete them.  Make sure the only thing left in the list is "Disk 0 Unallocated Space".  Select that, and hit Next.  This will allow the Windows installer to create the partition it needs, and to format it properly.

If there are no issues with the Ram in Computer 1, and there are no issues with the installation disc, Windows should then install without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Zero-filling the drive or secure erasing it or deleting all partitions will not affect the installation media. Either there's a problem with your DVD, or the drive is having problems reading the disc. Try again with a known good disc, or else if the DVD drive's bad use something like [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) to transfer the contents of the DVD to a USB stick and boot from that instead.

Answer (score 0):

refer to this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/606500/will-installing-windows-format-the-disk/606550#606550). the partition you created using partition magic will be having any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to install windows from a windows upgrade disk, which only lets you install to somewhere that already has windows on it.

You may need to find a different (or even old version) windows disc to install from first, and then install Windows 7.

I think I read somewhere that the Windows 7 upgrade EULA does not prohibit the use of a Windows 7 evaluation version being the previous version of windows that you are upgrading from.  But I don't buy upgrade versions of windows so I haven't checked that EULA.